# Does a analytic joint distribution necessarily have continuous marginals?

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, analyticity

Although the question actually popped up in a course about evolution equations, it seemed most natural to ask this in the context of joint distributions. Namely:

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two variables with joint distribution $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, which is jointly analytic in $x$ and $y$. Does this imply that the marginal distributions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ are continous?

I could create counterexamples if the statement is strengthened to imply differentiability (see below), or starting from smooth joint distributions, but the latter all had essential singularities (take for example [this](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=irKSXZ7kKFgC&lpg=PR12&ots=tZ-yfkygqM&dq=%22discontinuous%20marginal%22&pg=PA35#v=onepage&q=%20continuous%20bivariate%20density%20with%20a%20discontinuous%20marginal%20density.%203A%20continuous%20bivariate%20density%20with%20a%20discontinuous%20marginal%20density.%22discontinuous%20marginal%22&f=false), as provided by hcl14 ).

However, the derivatives of $f$ in $x$ and $y$ would not necessarily be integrable, so an obvious expansion in power series would not work, unfortunately. For (a little convoluted) example:

> Consider 
>   \begin{equation}
> f_{X,Y}(x,y):=\frac{2 \sin (x y)e^{-y} }{x^2+1}, \qquad x\geq0, y\geq 0
> \end{equation}
>   Then $f$ is analytic in $x$ and $y$ (however it is not holomorphic, it has poles in $x=\pm i$), and a straightforward calculation verifies that it defines a joint distribution. However, its power series in $y$ around $0$ is not integrable in $x$:
>   \begin{equation}
> f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{2 x y}{x^2+1}-\frac{2 x y^2}{x^2+1}+\mathcal{O}[y]^3
> \end{equation}
>   Finally, the marginal distribution $f_Y(y)$ (with a little help from Mathematica) seems not be differentiable in $0$.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you be a little more precise please? I don't understand how the counterexamples are supposed to work.

Comment: An example of continuous bivariate density with discontinuous marginal density can be found [here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=irKSXZ7kKFgC&lpg=PR12&ots=tZ-yfkygqM&dq=%22discontinuous%20marginal%22&pg=PA35#v=onepage&q=%20continuous%20bivariate%20density%20with%20a%20discontinuous%20marginal%20density.%203A%20continuous%20bivariate%20density%20with%20a%20discontinuous%20marginal%20density.%22discontinuous%20marginal%22&f=false).

Comment: Yes, nice example! The joint distribution of the example given by hcl14 is even smooth right? @William, it's similar to what I mentioned. However, it still contains a essential singularity at x=0, and is thus not analytic over its support.